# Use recieved Twilio text message as input in python script

Tags: python, twilio

I'd like to be able to message my twilio number and use that as an input for my script. I can send messages via twilio with python but would like to be able to receive them somehow.

Python 3.4
Twilio trial account

Comment: this is probably easier done by using twilio to lookup the text message email addresses and then using another utility like mailgun to actually send/receive the messages

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please? Am new to twilio and this area

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know to do this is to lookup the carriers using Twilio like so

```
    from twilio.rest.lookups import TwilioLookupsClient

    client = TwilioLookupsClient(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_API)
    twilio_number = client.phone_numbers.get(number, include_carrier_info=True, country_code="US")
    carrier_name = twilio_number.carrier['name']
    carrier_lib = {'Golden Telecom': 'sms.goldentele.com', 'Rogers Canada': 'pcs.rogers.com',
               'Western Wireless': 'cellularonewest.com', 'Cingular (Now AT&T)': 'txt.att.net',
               'Boost Mobile': 'myboostmobile.com', 'Cellular South': 'csouth1.com',
               'Bell Mobility': 'txt.bellmobility.ca', 'Fido': 'fido.ca', 'Comcast': 'comcastpcs.textmsg.com',
               'Virgin Mobile': 'vmobl.com', 'Southwestern Bell': 'email.swbw.com',
               'Corr Wireless Communications': 'corrwireless.net', 'Helio': 'messaging.sprintpcs.com',
               'T-Mobile': 'tmomail.net', 'Metro PCS': 'mymetropcs.com', 'US West': 'uswestdatamail.com',
               "President's Choice": 'txt.bell.ca', 'ACS Wireless': 'paging.acswireless.com', 'Tracfone': 'txt.att.net',
               'Carolina West Wireless': 'cwwsms.com', 'Virgin Mobile Canada': 'vmobile.ca', 'Qwest': 'qwestmp.com',
               'Public Service Cellular': 'sms.pscel.com', 'Cellular One': 'mobile.celloneusa.com',
               'Rogers AT&T Wireless': 'pcs.rogers.com', 'Houston Cellular': 'text.houstoncellular.net',
               'Centennial Wireless': 'cwemail.com', 'Metrocall': 'page.metrocall.com', 'Clearnet': 'msg.clearnet.com',
               'AT&T': 'txt.att.net', 'Verizon': 'vtext.com', '3 River Wireless': 'sms.3rivers.net',
               'BPL Mobile': 'bplmobile.com', 'Triton': 'tms.suncom.com',
               'Surewest Communicaitons': 'mobile.surewest.com', 'MTS': 'text.mtsmobility.com',
               'Alltel': 'message.alltel.com', 'Bell Mobility (Canada)': 'txt.bell.ca', 'Unicel': 'utext.com',
               'Inland Cellular Telephone': 'inlandlink.com', 'Solo Mobile': 'txt.bell.ca',
               'CenturyTel': 'messaging.centurytel.net', 'Bell Canada': 'bellmobility.ca',
               'Idea Cellular': 'ideacellular.net', 'Sprint': 'messaging.sprintpcs.com',
               'Illinois Valley Cellular': 'ivctext.com', 'Metrocall 2-way': 'my2way.com',
               'US Cellular': 'email.uscc.net', 'Satellink': 'satellink.net', 'Dobson': 'mobile.dobson.net',
               'Edge Wireless': 'sms.edgewireless.com', 'Nextel': 'messaging.nextel.com', 'MCI': 'pagemci.com',
               'Microcell': 'fido.ca', 'OnlineBeep': 'onlinebeep.net', 'PCS One': 'pcsone.net',
               'Sumcom': 'tms.suncom.com', 'Telus': 'msg.telus.com', 'Blue Sky Frog': 'blueskyfrog.com',
               'West Central Wireless': 'sms.wcc.net', 'Mobilcomm': 'mobilecomm.net',
               'Bluegrass Cellular': 'sms.bluecell.com', 'Midwest Wireless': 'clearlydigital.com',
               "Sprint Spectrum, L.P.": 'messaging.sprintpcs.com'}
    carrier_domain = carrier_lib[carrier_name] # Should implement a better lookup method, often times the carrier names vary slightly and will raise a KeyError
    phone_num_email_addres = str(10_digit_num) + "@" + carrier_domain
```

and then send/receive emails with mailgun https://documentation.mailgun.com/

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When your Twilio number receives an SMS message you can have Twilio send a webhook, an HTTP request, to a URL of your choice with all the details about the message. You can use this to receive the message and reply to it.

There is a great guide on [how to receive SMS messages using Python and Flask](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/sms/how-to-receive-and-reply-in-python) that I think could really help you out here.